# popup mesg whenever user logged into salesforce

Tags: text

Hi I want display a popup message,when ever user logged into salesforce,please help,thanks in advance

Comment: when do you want to display that popup?

Comment: after logged into salesforce

Comment: if enduder successfully logs into the salesforce

Comment: Do the user land in the home page when logged in? Do you use lightining mode or classic mode?

Comment: not landed in home page,in classic mode am doing

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by:
Have a VF page and set that as the default page for the default App. Everytime the user logs in this page will get executed and display the pop up alert and then you can redirect to the tab/page that you want the user to go.